# Android Studio 3.6 not able to place layouts by drag and drop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY3S7.png)

I am placing the layouts on approprite positions by dragging and dropping but in the emulator when opened they are all at the same position . please help

Comment: please post your .xml file

Comment: Provide your XML but it seems there are no Constraints on your Views and they all end up on TOP | LEFT. Consider watching/reading some tutorials before diving into coding.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio does not work that way. You cannot set the positions of views(items) by dragging them and placing them. You will have to set the constraints on the attribute tab. You can find the attribute tab at the top left corner. It is visible in the picture you uploaded. Click on that and the attributes window will open.

Then, when you click on a view, there is a square that appears in the attribute window. That square has 4 `+` signs around it. You have to click on one of the left or right `+` signs and enter a number. That would determine the horizontal position (distance from left or right margin) of the view. 
Similarly, set the vertical position by clicking on to our bottom `+`.

This is the method used to set the position of views graphically. There is a way to set them in the `xml` code. I guess you are not familiar with it. You will get to know how to do it in`xml` as you go on with Android development.

You can also set the position of a view with reference to other views instead of the margins. Please watch [this video](https://youtu.be/4N4bCdyGcUc) to know more about constraints.

Answer (score 0):

When you select one of your layout items, you'll see anchors on the sides.
Move an arrow from the selected view to the next one (or surrounding parent) to add a layout constraint.

[image]

An easy overview and quickstart how to use constraints in android studio, can be found here:
https://constraintlayout.com

And in the official documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout